# Rare Android Unable to Instantiate Application Exception

Tags: android, exception, instantiation

I'm seeing the following exception under Crashes in the dev console from time to time.

Whats puzzling about it is that google maps shows up in the call stack as if its calling or creating my app class - very confusing. Whats further weird is the "MyApp-2.apk" in the call stack - where it appends the "-2".

I do include the android.maps.jar file in the libs.

I would like to know how to recreate this if possible and how to prevent this from happening?

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.MyApp.MyCustomApp: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.MyApp.MyCustomApp" 
on path: /system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar:/data/app/com.MyApp-2.apk
    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:503)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4405)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:141)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1327)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5059)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.MyApp.MyCustomApp" on path: /system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar:/data/app/com.MyApp-2.apk
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:967)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:498)
    ... 11 more
```

Manifest Application Tag:

```
 <application
        android:name=".MyApp"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme" >
```

I'm using these JARS: android-support-v4-r2-googlemaps.jar + android-support-v4.jar

Comment: can you post your manifest's application tag? would be helpful for someone to help you. And also your ADT version in case if you are using eclipse :)

Comment: Hi, sure I'll add the app tag. I'm also not using eclipse, using Android Studio.

Comment: And as you said, "Crashes in the dev console", did you find any specific api level or device?

Comment: I have 3 instances on Android 4.1 and 1 on 4.4. Samsung S3, HTC One, & Droid Razr are the devices.

Comment: @AlexVPerl do you have this class? "com.nyctrans.it.nycTransitApp"

Comment: Sry - that's the actual class name. For privacy reasons I masked/replaced it with MyCustomApp in the call stack. And yes the class is present. I extend the Application class.

Comment: Have you tried uninstall then Project -> Clean,

Comment: This is happening in production - so can't clean :) But I always clean prior to generating a signed apk as well.

Comment: I've had this occur to me too.  Just a random crash on a user's phone and it can't find the class files in DexPathList.

Answer (score 2):

The prime reason why a Class within your application would be present on your test devices but missing at runtime on some others would be if your class has a dependency on some external feature which is missing on those devices.  For example, if you used some Google API which is not part of AOSP and so missing on a plain AOSP build, or a vendor build which does not license these, then your class will be pruned at install time as its dependencies cannot be resolved.

A common reason for your app finding its way into such circumstances might be someone running an inconsistently assembled "custom ROM" on their device.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense. I do use Google MapView in my app - but I dont do anything out of the ordinary, just map markers and polylines. And I"m including these JARS: android-support-v4-r2-googlemaps.jar + android-support-v4.jar